# Unable to use Shiny downloadHandler to download a png file, get 'down.html' instead

Tags: r, shiny

I try to use the `downloadHandler` in `shiny`. I wrote some simple codes for downloading a png file, but it doesn't work. When I click the download button, it shows downloading for 'down.html'.

Here are the codes I tried.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadButton("down","Download .png")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$down <- downloadHandler(
   filename = "test.png",
    content = function(file) {
      png(file)
      plot(1:5)
      dev.off
    },
   contentType = "image/png")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your content function you need to call `dev.off()` (i.e. add brackets) and then it works fine.